# Stuck in Terminal after echo

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line-tool

I opened Linux Terminal and entered `echo I can't hear you`. I expected the next line to print "I can't hear you," but instead it printed >. I think it had something to do with the apostrophe, but now I cannot enter any new commands. No matter what I try to enter after this, the next line always begins with >. I'm not sure if there's a specific term for this situation or how to get out of it. I lack the technical terminology to describe this problem and cannot tell if anyone else has asked this question before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to embed a single quote in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602752/i-want-to-embed-a-single-quote-in-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to leave the terminal with `Ctrl + C` or `Ctrl + D`. This is caused because you did not close the opened quote. You can also type a closing quote to exit the `>`.

[image]

The arrow `>` means, terminal is waiting for you to close the opened quote.

If you want to use a quote in your echo, you can escape it with backslash

```sh
echo Trump\'s Tower
```

You can read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773278/dquote-result-of-a-execution-a-program-in-linux-shell) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ctrl + c or Ctrl + d will get you out. The echo command can handle any number of words with regular letters and numbers (A-Z, a-z, 0-9). You can avoid the problem of getting stuck by using quotes. Double quotes or single quotes will both work, but there are differences to note.

```sh
# Double quotes: this works well since it uses a different quote type so the ' is okay
echo "Hello World's"

# Single quotes: this will cause the same problem because there is an unpaired quote 
echo 'Hello World's'
```